# Browser to mobile calling directly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sip

Is there any way that i can develop an app to support audio calling, instant message and voice calling from browser to any mobile/PSTN number directly using javascript?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? Like maybe a flow of how you want this to happen?

Comment: Suppose "John" and "Jack" are two persons who want to talk each other. John is calling Jack through browser and Jack is receiving his call form mobile means the call event fired directly. Is it clear?

Comment: So, a url in a browser that launches that device's normal phone app, or the call is 'processed' directly in the browser via html5?  your intents are still not very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/client). Find the "Twilio Client" section on the right-hand side of [the how-to docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto) to see example use cases.

Especially take a look at the [soft phone](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-browser-soft-phone) example.